# Regex to get string between speechmarks anywhere within a string

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a project where I am trying to extract a string between two speechmarks anywhere within a string. Its almost working except for one thing.

Lets say I have the line

`"04\/06\/2019 17:56:45:\tTook 0 seconds to read lines for log 'Log Agent`

The idea I'll do two regex matches, one for a string where it doesn't have an exclamation mark for example I'll do a regex search to match `"Took 0 seconds"` and another to look for something like `!"Took 0 seconds"`

I have the following regex to look for a string without it starting with an exclamation mark.

```
$regex = '/[^.!](["\'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\2.)*?\1/m';
            $matches = null;
            preg_match_all($regex, $this->searchString, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

But the above regex only matches the string if there's something before the string it doesn't find anything

E.g. if the search string is 
`"Took 0 seconds"`
it doesn't get found

if its 
`some other content "Took 0 seconds"`
then it correctly finds the string `Took 0 seconds` in the regex match.

So basically what I am asking how can I change my regex that it extract the string between the speech marks anywhere, even if its right at the beginning.

**UPDATE**

Try and clarify what I'm doing. I'm creating a search parser to find certain strings within a database.

The search within the database will either look for individual keywords (not related to this question that easily done) and looking for a particular string within the database. So if my search string `"took 0 seconds"`, then the database would return any rows that contain a record `took 0 seconds`. If the search string is `!"took 0 seconds"` then I'd be able to check the database for not contains `Took 0 seconds`.

If my search string was `keyword1 keyword2 "took 0 seconds" keyword 3`
then the regex would return `"took 0 seconds"`

Below is a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qYKqT0/2) link that gives some examples and what the problem is, you'll notice the first one where it is just "Took 0 seconds" on its own doesn't get matched.

Comment: What are _speechmarks_?  If you mean something like quotes, then your example doesn't seem to have anything to do with those.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully I've clarified a bit what I am trying to do

Comment: Not sure I well understand but how about a negative lookbehind: `(?<![.!])(["\'])(?:(?=(\\\\?))\2.)*?\1`

Comment: What if you just use this REGEX instead `(took [0-9]+ seconds)` ? See here : https://regex101.com/r/qYKqT0/4

Comment: Did you mean to use a tempered greedy token for only group 1 perhaps? 
 `(?<![.!])(["\'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1` https://regex101.com/r/U1IC6u/2

Comment: @tcj That was just an example, the "took 0 seconds" was just an example, it could be absolutely anything.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that seems to be what I am after

Comment: @Boardy oh ok I see better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Toto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/toto) pointed out in the comments you could use a negative lookbehind instead of matching the characters in a character class.

What you might do is update your pattern to only make use of the first capturing group. As your pattern makes use or a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) solution, the pattern might look like:

```
(?<![.!])(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1
```

- `(?<![.!])`
- `(["'])` Capture in group 1 either `"` or `'`
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` Loop 0+ times matching any char while what on the right is not group 1
- `\1` Match backreference to group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1IC6u/2)

Note that due to the `*` quantifier it will also match `""`

Another way to get those matches could be to use a non greedy match `.*?` followed by group 1 `\1`

```
(?<![.!])(["\']).*?\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1IC6u/3)

Comment: Thanks that's great